# Format numbers into USD - PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project and I have three category's,

```
1 = last payment amount (integer, ex: 100 = $1, 2000, = $20.)
2 = account balance: (integer, ex: 5000 = $50, 20 = $.20.)
3 = formatted amount (USD format without the $, ex: 1.00 = $1.00, 10.00 = $10.00)
```

Now when using these three options to update accordingly, I use a format function in JavaScript.  But now I have an auto reload feature that does everything in PHP.  The issue is that I am having trouble formatting, lets say `1000 to 10.00`.  Here is the problem:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$addAmount = money_format('%i', $accBal);
```

Lets say `$accBal = 5000`.  So that should be `$5.00`, but using the `money_format...` it converts to  `USD 5,000`.

What could I do to format it appropriately?

Comment: how is 5000 equal to 5 dollars?

Comment: Its just how I am working my system because I am using stripe API and that is how they work

Comment: thats to crazy and way to prone to problems in the future

Comment: No its not.  This way you can use it for multiple currency's

Comment: I am reformatting only for my purposes.  So that I can display `$5.00` without it being `$500`.

Comment: if its no problem, you would not be here with your .... problem :-)

Comment: Lol @Dagon no I don't mean that, I am talking about how the API works. Really nice.

Comment: What's the problem with dividing by 100? I don't see why you aren't doing that...

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe any hundred number would equal some sort of dollar in USD and any thousand type number would be in the ten's USD.  If that makes sense?

Comment: @dagon All of his examples except the last one are x100

Comment: money_format('%i', $accBal/100);

Comment: Lol I feel very dumb at the moment, how silly of me.  That works great :) Write it and I'll mark it.

Comment: Hey is their a way to disable the USD writing it does when formatting the money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the numbers are all just the dollar/cent amounts multiplied by 100, you can simply divide by 100 to get it to a normal decimal number.

```
money_format('%i', $accBal/100);
```

I'm not sure if you can remove USD or not, I don't have a system with money_format that I can test it on, try the ! flag.